# Setting WPF Window Background Image at App Start Up

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an application that shows a different background images according to environment state, this app is launched at user logon via Windows Registry (HKEY_CURRENT_USER).
 After user login the application is launched but it crashes afterward, complaining that the Uri for the image is not valid. 
Notably if the application is launched manually by the user (i.e. double clicking) all works fine, and the corresponding image is successfully loaded.
Images are configured with *Build Action = None, and Copy to output directory= Copy if newer*.

This markup in my main window:

```
<Window.Background>
    <ImageBrush x:Name="imgBackground" ></ImageBrush>
</Window.Background>
```

Then in codebehind I want to set the corresponding image:

```
imgBackground.ImageSource = 
     new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Resources\Background.png",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

Images are configured with *Build Action = None, and Copy to output directory= Copy if newer*.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the `CD` (current directory) set at application startup. How are you starting the application on user log-on? A shortcut in the start menu or what? If it is a shortcut, you might get along by setting the "Start In:" property pointing to your app's directory.

Comment: @LeandroTaset,  application loading is configured via user Registry at user logon, for unknown reasons in this cases the application cant resolve the path to files. Notably if the application is launched manually by the user (i.e. double clicking) all works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better load the image as embedded resource.

Set the Build Action to Resource (and do not copy to output directory), and load it via a [Resource Pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx):

```
imgBackground.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(
    new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/Background.png"));
```

Comment: No, in code behind you'll have to write a full Pack Uri.